# How do you update/create a null field in a new record with Prisma

Tags: graphql, prisma

I'm setting up permissions for user on a CRUD app, I want to give myself the permission of `ADMIN` but I can't seem to do it. I have set up my data type for a `user` as follows:

`datamodel.graphql`:

```
type User {
    id: ID! @unique
    name: String!
    email: String! @unique
    password: String!
    resetToken: String
    resetTokenExpiry: String
    permissions: [Permission]
}
```

`schema.graphql`:

```
type User {
    id: ID!
    name: String!
    email: String!
    permissions: [Permission!]!
}
```

When using my Prisma console, I can fill out all the fields *except* for `permissions`.

[image]

And when trying to update an existing user's permissions, I can't seem to type anything in that field to update it. Is my schema wrong?

Answer (score 1):

I believe permission is an enum(I am kinda recognising that schema from the Wes Bos Course).

You can add an item to an enum by using the three-dot menu > Add an Item

[image]